# Dictionary with restricted keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash-map, meta-programming

I'm currently building some software that works with systemd unit files, and I've been trying to improve how we construct the unit files.

This is all running in Python 3.4

This first block is the base classes I'm building things up with.

```
class LimitedDict(dict):
    """
    Sub Class of the dictionary object that restricts the allowed keys.
    The allowed keys are set when creating the object.

    >>> a = LimitedDict(allowed_keys=['foo'], foo='bar')
    >>> a == {'foo': 'bar'}
    True

    >>> ok_keywords = {'foo': 'bar'}
    >>> a = LimitedDict(allowed_keys=['foo'], **ok_keywords)
    >>> a == {'foo': 'bar'}
    True

    >>> LimitedDict(allowed_keys=['foo'], foo='bar', fail='true')
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "<stdin>", line 13, in __init__
    KeyError: "key: 'fail' not in allowed keys: '['foo']'"

    >>> not_ok_keywords = {'foo': 'bar', 'fail': 'oops'}
    >>> LimitedDict(allowed_keys=['foo'], **not_ok_keywords)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "<stdin>", line 13, in __init__
    KeyError: "key: 'fail' not in allowed keys: '['foo']'"

    >>> a = LimitedDict(allowed_keys=['foo'], foo='bar')
    >>> a['fail'] = 'true'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
        ...
    KeyError: "key: 'fail' not in allowed keys: '['foo']'"
    """
    _allowed_keys = list()

    def __init__(self, allowed_keys, **kwargs):
        if not isinstance(allowed_keys, list):
            AttributeError("'allowed_keys' must be a list")
        self._allowed_keys = allowed_keys
        for key in kwargs.keys():
            if key not in self._allowed_keys:
                raise KeyError("key: '" + str(key) + "' not in allowed keys: '" + str(self._allowed_keys) + "'")
            self[key] = kwargs[key]

    def __setitem__(self, key, val):
        if key not in self._allowed_keys:
           raise KeyError("key: '" + str(key) + "' not in allowed keys: '" + str(self._allowed_keys) + "'")
        dict.__setitem__(self, key, val)


class UnitDict(LimitedDict):
    """
    This LimitedDict object is further customized for use in building a
    json representation of a systemd unit file. The additional restrictions
    ensure we don't introduce elements outside the allowed values for a
    systemd unit file.

    Create a dictionary with the correct keys:
    >>> a = UnitDict(name='Test', desiredState='Loaded', options='Test')
    >>> a == {'name': 'Test', 'desiredState': 'Loaded', 'options': 'Test'}
    True

    Ignore incorrect keys
    >>> a = UnitDict(name='Test', desiredState='Loaded', options='Test', ignored='True')
    >>> a == {'options': 'Test', 'name': 'Test', 'desiredState': 'Loaded'}
    True
    """
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super_kwargs = {
            'name': kwargs['name'],
            'desiredState': kwargs['desiredState'],
            'options': kwargs['options']}
        super().__init__(allowed_keys=list(super_kwargs.keys()), **super_kwargs)


class UnitOptionDict(LimitedDict):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super_kwargs = {
            'name': kwargs['name'],
            'section': kwargs['section'],
            'value': kwargs['value']}
        super().__init__(allowed_keys=list(super_kwargs.keys()), **super_kwargs)
```

This is the code I want feedback on. I'm fairly sure this can be improved. Most likely with metaclasses but after much reading, I'm still not completely sure just how to construct such a metaclass, or if that really is the best way to refactor this to be cleaner.

```
def build_option_dict(caller, **kwargs):
    if not kwargs['value']:
        raise KeyError
    if not isinstance(kwargs['value'], str):
        raise ValueError
    return {
        'section': str(caller.__class__.__qualname__).split('.')[-2],
        'name': str(caller.__class__.__qualname__).split('.')[-1],
        'value': str(kwargs['value'])
    }


class MightyMorphingMetaMagic(UnitOptionDict):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super_kwargs = build_option_dict(self, **kwargs)
        super().__init__(allowed_keys=list(super_kwargs.keys()), **super_kwargs)


class OptionSections:
    class Unit:
        class Description(MightyMorphingMetaMagic):
            pass

        class After(MightyMorphingMetaMagic):
            pass

        class Require(MightyMorphingMetaMagic):
            pass

    class Service:
        class TimeoutStartSec(MightyMorphingMetaMagic):
            pass

        class ExecStartPre(MightyMorphingMetaMagic):
            pass

        class ExecStart(MightyMorphingMetaMagic):
            pass

        class ExecStartPost(MightyMorphingMetaMagic):
            pass

        class ExecStopPre(MightyMorphingMetaMagic):
            pass

        class ExecStop(MightyMorphingMetaMagic):
            pass

        class ExecStopPost(MightyMorphingMetaMagic):
            pass
```

The way this ends up being used is typically like this, building a json representation from a fairly stable list of unit file parts.

```
from lib.systemd import OptionSections as Sections
unit_json = [
        Sections.Unit.Description(value=str(self.description)),
        Sections.Service.ExecStartPre(value=str(self.execstartpre)),
        Sections.Service.ExecStart(value=str(self.execstart)),
        Sections.Service.ExecStop(value=str(self.execstop))
    ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To re-factor this code firstly I'd recommend using [packages](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages) instead of nested classes here, so create a package named `Sections` and create two more packages named `Unit` and `Services` inside of it, you can also move the dictionary definitions inside of this package say in a file named `dicts.py` and each of those inner packages then can import the required dict(s) if required.

The structure will look something like this:

> ```
> $ tree Sections/
> Sections/
> ├── dicts.py
> ├── __init__.py
> ├── Service
> │   └── __init__.py
> └── Unit
>     └── __init__.py
> ```

Here to use the nested dot notation `Sections.Unit.Description` we import the required items from each of the individual packages to Sections's `__init__.py` file:

```python
$ cat Sections/__init__.py 
from .Unit import After, Description
from .Service import ExecStartPre, ExecStart, ExecStartPost, ExecStopPre,\
    ExecStop, ExecStopPost, TimeoutStartSec
```

Similarly the contents of `Unit/__init__.py` and `Services/__init__.py` are:

```python
$ cat Sections/Unit/__init__.py 
from ..dicts import MightyMorphingMetaMagic

class Description(MightyMorphingMetaMagic):
    pass

class After(MightyMorphingMetaMagic):
    pass

class Require(MightyMorphingMetaMagic):
    pass

$ cat Sections/Service/__init__.py 
from ..dicts import MightyMorphingMetaMagic

class TimeoutStartSec(MightyMorphingMetaMagic):
    pass

class ExecStartPre(MightyMorphingMetaMagic):
    pass

class ExecStart(MightyMorphingMetaMagic):
    pass

class ExecStartPost(MightyMorphingMetaMagic):
    pass

class ExecStopPre(MightyMorphingMetaMagic):
    pass

class ExecStop(MightyMorphingMetaMagic):
    pass

class ExecStopPost(MightyMorphingMetaMagic):
    pass
```

Now in your main script you can simply import `Sections`(considering this packages lies in the [module search path](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path)):

```python
import Sections

unit_json = [

        Sections.Unit.Description(value=str(self.description)),
        Sections.Service.ExecStartPre(value=str(self.execstartpre)),
        Sections.Service.ExecStart(value=str(self.execstart)),
        Sections.Service.ExecStop(value=str(self.execstop))
    ]
```

---

Now to accommodate this package based version we will have to make some changes:

- We can't use `__qualname__` now, an alternative is to use the `__module__` argument of the class object.
- Instead of `caller.__class__` to get instance's class we can use `type(caller)`. In new-style classes both do the same thing.
- Instead of using a `list` for `_allowed_keys` it's better to use a `set` as it stores only unique items and provides O(1) lookups.
- We can allow all types of iterables to be passed as `_allowed_keys` instead of just `list`, we can check this using an abstract base class [`collections.Iterable`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Iterable).
- As `allowed_keys` is kind of compulsory argument here, better make it a key-word only argument with default value of `None`, this will also help in separating it from normal kwargs.
- Use string formatting instead of `str()` calls and +, plus using `'str(some_key)'` can be confusing to the user when `some_key` is `1` or `'1'`. A better way is to use the `repr` representation of the object, in new-style string formatting we can obtain it using `{!r}`.
- While checking for a key in a dict simply use `if key in dict`, the `.keys()` call on the dict is unnecessary and will take O(N) time in Python 2.
- To get the keys of a dictionary use `list(some_dict)` instead `list(some_dict.keys())`, this works as is in both Python 2 and 3. But again we should better pass the keys in the form of a set whenever possible.
- Use `for key, value in some_dict.items():` if you want key as well corresponding value while iterating over a dict.
- I noticed that you are calculating `super_kwargs` inside `__init__` of each class that too from the `kwargs` passed to that class. I'd say why not define `_allowed_key` in that class itself, and the call `super().__init__(allowed_keys=self._allowed_keys, **kwargs)`. Now the baseclass `LimitedDict` will handle the rest.
- To support the `super().__init__` I've used the same signature in each class's `__init__` method.
- I cannot think of a way to use a metaclass here myself, so I moved `build_option_dict` inside of the class.
- `if not kwargs['value']: raise KeyError` doesn't make much sense, better store the value in some variable and if the key is missing Python will raise an error itself.

Now my `dicts.py` looks like(removed doctests to save some space):

```python
from collections import Iterable


class LimitedDict(dict):

    _allowed_keys = set()

    def __init__(self, *, allowed_keys=None, **kwargs):

        if not isinstance(allowed_keys, Iterable):
            AttributeError("'allowed_keys' must be an iterable")
        self._allowed_keys = allowed_keys
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            if key not in self._allowed_keys:
                raise KeyError("key: {!r} not in allowed keys: {!r}".format(key,
                                                                            self._allowed_keys))
            self[key] = value

    def __setitem__(self, key, val):
        if key not in self._allowed_keys:
            raise KeyError("key: {!r} not in allowed keys: {!r}".format(key,
                                                                        self._allowed_keys))
        dict.__setitem__(self, key, val)


class UnitDict(LimitedDict):

    _allowed_keys = {'name', 'desiredState', 'options'}

    def __init__(self, *, allowed_keys=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(allowed_keys=self._allowed_keys, **kwargs)


class UnitOptionDict(LimitedDict):
    _allowed_keys = {'name', 'section', 'value'}

    def __init__(self, *, allowed_keys=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(allowed_keys=self._allowed_keys, **kwargs)


class MightyMorphingMetaMagic(UnitOptionDict):

    def build_option_dict(self, **kwargs):
        value = kwargs['value']
        if not isinstance(value, str):
            raise ValueError("'value' must be a of type str")

        return {
            'section': type(self).__module__.split('.')[-1],
            'name': type(self).__name__,
            'value': str(kwargs['value'])
        }

    def __init__(self,  *, allowed_keys=None, **kwargs):
        super_kwargs = self.build_option_dict(**kwargs)
        super().__init__(allowed_keys=self._allowed_keys, **super_kwargs)
```

Comment: This definitely structures the code a bit better, and I'll likely adopt a number of the things here. However based on my reasonably proficient understanding of Abstract Syntax Tree magic, and my basic understanding of metaclasses, I still feel that a substantially more "clean, clear, and compact" version is possible.

Comment: @Techdragon Tim peters once said: "Metaclasses are deeper magic than 99% of users should ever worry about. If you wonder whether you need them, you don't." :-)

Comment: I do agree with that. However I have updated my original post to better explain why I feel metaclasses may be the appropriate answer. At this point, I have 3 ways I suspect I can get what I want in terms of 'terseness', Metaclasses, abusing the AST tree, 'virtual packages' via overriding the import handlers so that `from lib.systemd import OptionSections` invents all the subclasses defined the override logic at runtime. I'd like to use metaclasses since, expanding on Tim's sentiment, the AST is more than 99.9% need, and Import overrides is more than 99.99% of us need.